# Enterprise distribution certificate is going to expire in one month

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution

Our distribution certificate is going to expire in september. I red apple documentation, but there is not much information about renewing the certificate. Will we have to reship all the apps again with the new certificates?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the it only checks the app's signature at install time. So you don't have to mass-redeploy every app out in the wild.

Comment: I didn't need to redeploy my app when the certificate expired.  I think you just need the new one if you build it again.

Comment: 'An app won’t run if its distribution certificate has expired.' Thats what it says on apple documentation.

Comment: My mistake. I just set my iPhone to the year 2032 and tapped my app. It came up with a dialog that said the provisioning profile had expired. Time to re-deploy! ;-)